# Can I remove the passphrase from my Bitcoin Wallet?

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, passphrase

I'm using the standard Mac Bitcoin client and I added a passphrase. I'd like to remove that passphrase. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't know if the client allows you to do it without tricks, but in the worst case scenario you can still send all your coins to another address, create a new wallet, and send them back into this new one.

Comment: I have the same problem with a wallet that is encrypted. I tried to remove it and if I reinstall a new client it comes back as the old wallet. I installed to a new location, did a registry cleaner and it comes back as the locked wallet. The trick of sending the bitcoins to another wallet don't work. It requires a passphrase to send them.

Comment: "I have the same problem with a wallet that is encrypted. I tried to remove it and if I reinstall a new client it comes back as the old wallet. I installed to a new location, did a registry cleaner and it comes back as the locked wallet. The trick of sending the bitcoins to another wallet don't work. It requires a passphrase to send them." Start of Winkey + R type %appdata% and found folder Bitcoin. Save the file wallet.dat in case! Delete it form folder and the program will generate a new address for the wallet! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Bitcoin.org client does not yet have the feature to remove encryption from a wallet.  You can use a single space as the encryption key but there no way to get it to no longer use encryption.

That is expected to be implemented in a future release.

In the meantime, those that want this will create a new wallet and leave it unencrypted, and send their coins from the encrypted wallet to it.

Comment: how to transfer keys from one wallet to another without transferring funds with a FEE ?

Comment: Set fee to zero and wait or import/export the keys.

Answer (score 6):

You can dump your old wallet to a backup file, restart the program to generate a new wallet and import your old wallet into it.

Assuming you are in the directory where your wallet file is located, using the command line that would look like this:

```
bitcoind walletpassphrase "xxx" 60
bitcoind dumpwallet "wallet.dat.backup"
bitcoind stop
mv wallet.dat wallet.dat.old
bitcoind -daemon
bitcoind importwallet wallet.dat.backup
```

I would be interested in a less dirty way, if anybody knows one.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It is possible.

Either the UI supports it or it does not. You are better equipped to find out than I am but I suspect it does not (yet).

If it does not you can either:

- Export the keys, move the wallet files (rather than deleting it, so you can move it back if things to wrong, on Mac the wallet files are here: ~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/), import the keys.
- implement it yourself / pay someone to implement if for you
- find an alternative client to do it for you (Armory might have it, a list is [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Category:Clients))
- find an alternative client to open it and export the private keys, so you can import them into a new unencrypted wallet.
- when all else fails: transact your Bitcoin towards a new unencrypted wallet and ditch the old, encrypted, wallet. Be sure to tell people you've migrated, your old addresses are still in your encrypted wallet.

Comment: * pay someone to implement it for you * use the standard client to export your keys, make a new wallet, and import the keys

Comment: I guess that's almost mentioned in the third bullet, and is the most obvious answer. I'll correct. Maybe I didn't really understand the question last time?